# parse color VS parse int

Tags: java, android, parseint

I have a problem changing the background color randomly:
First, I try to use parseColor In the Colorclass:

```
public class Colors {

       public String[] colors = {
            "#39add1", // light blue
            "#3079ab", // dark blue
            "#c25975" // mauve
       };

       public int getcolor() {
          Random randomGenerator = new Random();
          String color = "";

          int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);

          color = colors[randomNumber];
          int colorAsInt = Color.parseColor(color);
          return colorAsInt;
      }
}
```

And in the Activity class:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              int color = mColors.getcolor();
              relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
};
```

It works perfectly:
But when I try to use String for return type of getcolor and use parse int in the activity class, when i run the app it gives me an error :Unfortunately app has stopped.

The color class:

```
public String getcolor() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    String color = "";

    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);

    color = colors[randomNumber];
    return color;
}
```

And the activity class:

```
 View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
               String color = mColors.getcolor();
               relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(color));
        }
 };
```

Why this problem happens?

Comment: You need to look at the logcat to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(color)` cant parse the string because its not an integer string `"#39add1"`.
You have to use `Color.parseColor(color)` like the first function.

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
```

Comment: what is integer String?

Comment: The string that contain numbers only like "123" and "12.34"

Answer (score 0):

Change your colors definition to

```
public int[] colors = {
    0x39add1, // light blue
    0x3079ab, // dark blue
    0xc25975 // mauve
};
```

and use

```
setBackgroundColor(colors[0]);
```

Comment: Is there any special difference between int color and string color ?